# Java broadcast group no longer working

Tags: java, networking, broadcast, multicast

I have designed a system in Java where a server creates a broadcast group and sends packets to clients who are also part of the same group. It is a simple multicast socket according to the Java documentation, i.e.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html

This has been working fine for over a year, but since yesterday it seems that the client is no longer able to receive data coming from the broadcast group. I ran Wireshark to check that the packets were arriving and it seems that they are. I assume something on the network has changed because this program has been running fine for a long time, but I am at a loss as to what the problem could be. I found a similar question below but am unsure if it is related:

[Java: Unable to receive multicast data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469264/java-unable-to-recieve-multicast-data)

I appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks.

Comment: So many questions :) You say that you have several clients, are all affected or only one? Has something happened to the clients? Updates, Patches, new Software, etc. How are the clients made up? What is their Operation System? Which java version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All the clients are affected. I'm using Windows machines for server and clients and Java 1.6 (jMonkeyEngine). I'm not aware of any software updates or changes, as I said the program has been running fine for a long time. It seems strange that it would stop working all of a sudden.